# Connection to ADSL router is invisible

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet

I have an ADSL router connected to my PC using USB; internet works ok, but there is no appropriate network connection in the list of connections. I cannot change settings, share connection, etc. Is this normal or a bug? How to change settings of this connection?

UPD ipconfig names this connection as "Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3". When I pull out USB, it disappears from the list. However, this connection is never shown under Control Panel/Connections

Comment: Looks like you are using the "modem way"? Can you present the output of the command line tool "ipconfig"?

Comment: @Robert, see update